# How to pass dependencies to prototype functions in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, prototypal-inheritance

Is there a less verbose way of accessing dependencies (i.e. constructor parameters) in prototype functions? Particularly for [AngularJS Services](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services).

I only know of

```js
function SomeSrvc($http, ...other deps...) {
  var srvc = this;

  // Verbose way of storing dependencies
  srvc.$http = $http;
  srvc.dep2 = dep2;
  srvc.dep3 = dep3;
  srvc.dep4 = dep4;
}

SomeSrvc.prototype.doSomething = function() {
  var srvc = this;
  // Do stuff with srvc.$http and other srvc.deps...
};
```

Comment: This is how I've been doing it.  I think that it might be one reason why JS people tend not to use the object's `prototype` all that frequently ... But I've always liked it even if it is slightly more verbose.

Comment: You could just inject `$injector`.

Comment: @elclanrs Can you show me the above example using `$injector`? Does it change the verbose way of passing to prototype functions?

Comment: You'd do `function SomeSrvc($injector)` then `srvc.$http = $injector.get('$http')`, so you still have to assign it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shortest I know would be avoiding using prototype in an outer scope and simply use closures:

```
function SomeSrvc($http, ...other deps...) {
  var srvc = this;

  srvc.doSomething = function() {
    // just use $http without this / srvc
  };
}
```

Short and nice. If you really like prototype-like syntax, just adjust the indentation (but in my opinion this would be uglier):

```
function SomeSrvc($http, ...other deps...) {
  var srvc = this;



srvc.doSomething = function() {
  // Do stuff with srvc.$http and other srvc.deps...
};

}
```

This gives you the same effect - the object created with a `new` operator will have this function and angular services are created this way.

Additionally, this way has a really good side-effect. It does not create the variables on the service object, so they can be considered `private`, when assigning all your variables to the service makes them `public` and could be accessed from another angular module. Currently by just injecting your service you are able to use all injected modules by just calling e.g.

```
SomeSrvc.$http
```

which is totally against the whole idea of dependency injection.

Comment: Thanks, this certainly answers the question for less verbose. I thought about using it previously, but I didn't want to lose prototypical inheritance.

Comment: @lebolo Why do you need a prototypical inheritance? The angular services are singletons, they are created **once** with a `new` operator. You cannot reuse constructor function elsewhere, so prototype is just obsolete. In my opinion at least...

Comment: I've used it before ([this](http://blog.mgechev.com/2013/12/18/inheritance-services-controllers-in-angularjs/) shows an example in the _module.service_ section).

Comment: yes, but in this example there are two "classes" which is slightly going against the _angular way_ which instead of inheritance offers dependency injection for model and directives for views. And even with the method I proposed above you can still do inheritance by first creating object with a `new SomeSrvc()` and taking it's prototype. Just one step more

Answer (score 1):

This is actually an official way described in [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di)

```
function SomeClass(greeter) {
  this.greeter = greeter;
}

SomeClass.prototype.doSomething = function(name) {
  this.greeter.greet(name);
}
```

But I would consider to use ES2015 classes syntax instead.

```
export default class SomeClass {
  constructor(greeter) {
    this._greeter = greeter;
  }

  doSomething() {
    this._greeter.greet(name);
  }
}
```

You can read about it more [here](https://www.timroes.de/2015/07/29/using-ecmascript-6-es6-with-angularjs-1-x/)

Comment: Thanks, missed that part in the documentation!

Comment: how is this less verbose?

Comment: @smnbbrv It's not, but it's useful to know that this is the "official" way to do it in AngularJS. Makes me feel less like a chump =P

Comment: @lebolo angular guys still use `$scope`-variables-way instead of this way on the most pages of their documentation, but it does not mean it is a right way to go...

Comment: Personally I use ES2015, It's especially handy when you need extend a class

Comment: @smnbbrv You're right, which is why I chose your answer

Comment: @DmitriyNevzorov personally I use typescript which allows creating variables directly in the constructor :) e.g. `constructor(private $http)` and it's already received and assigned

Comment: Using prototypes decreases memory usage if the controller is used often, as the functions do not have to be initialised all the time.

Answer (score 0):

for services, not controllers, I've been doing something a little different

```
module.factory('myService', function(dep1, dep2){
    var createInternal=function(){ 
        var internal = Object.create(proto);
        internal.init( ... ); 
        return internal;
    };
    var service = function(){ 
        var internal = createInternal(); 
        return { 
            doSomething: function(a, b, c){ return internal.doSomething(a,b,c); },
            ...
        };
    };
    var proto = { 
        init: function( ... ){ 
                  dep1.greet();
                  dep2.doSomethingElse(); 
                  ... 
              },
        doSomething: function(a, b, c){ 
                  dep1.grito(b);
                  dep2.haceOtraCosa();
              },
        ...
    };
    return service();
});
```

It's a little bit different, but it breaks it up into a header and a list of prototype functions, which I like.

Comment: doesn't look like less verbose at all... Looks like spaghetti to me; to create one empty function on a service you use at least 20 lines of code...

Comment: to me, I'm either interested in what the service does, or what the prototype functions do, and so yeah, there's a lot of boilerplate, but the interesting parts of the code are easier to read because of it.

Comment: you could at least put some of these functions in a special service and reuse them everywhere. I really believe one can take half of these things in some external function which will bootstrap your service automatically in one line

Comment: it's not about memory, it's about total unreadability of your code

Comment: obviously we disagree